# Firebase storage upload on React submit form

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage

Is it possible upload files on submit? Not sure how to combine these two: Now it has to uploads file first then update name or creates new name without file on submit.

```
<form ref={(input) => { this.locationForm = input }} onSubmit={this.createLocation} >
    <input ref={(input) => this.name = input} type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <input ref={(input) => this.file = input} type="file" onChange={this.uploadFile} id="fileButton" />
</form>
```

and

```
   createLocation(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const store = {
            ['store']: {
                name: this.name.value,
                desc: this.desc.value
            }
        }

        this.props.setStore(store);
    }

    uploadFile(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('test/' + file.name);

        storageRef.put(file);
    }
```

`setStore` calls redux function and updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, do the following.

```
<Input type="file" id="my-file-id" /> // no need of on change listener
```

Then in the createLocation function

```
var myFile= document.getElementById('my-file-id').files[0];
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('test/' + myFile.name);

storageRef.put(file);
```

Note: The component "Input", I have imported from 'antd', I feel above works with "input" component of jsx also if not , do the following

```
npm install antd // for node modules
```

In you component

```
import { Input } from 'antd'
```